# Codeigniter db->where_in adding ''

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a problem with [where_in](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data) . I am trying to get the shop name which possess the lookbook had the specific point id

```
$this->db->select('shop');
$this->db->from('shopify_lookbook');
$this->db->where_in('lookbook_id', 'SELECT lookbook_id FROM shopify_point WHERE point_id = $pointid');
```

The problem is the query it generate

```
SELECT `shop` FROM `shopify_lookbook` WHERE `lookbook_id` IN('SELECT lookbook_id FROM shopify_point WHERE point_id = 543')
```

It will give blank but when I try in mysql without '' in `IN()` like below

```
SELECT `shop` FROM `shopify_lookbook` WHERE `lookbook_id` IN(SELECT lookbook_id FROM shopify_point WHERE point_id = 543)
```

It returns the shop name that I want. How can I erase `''` in `$this->db->where_in()`

Comment: you dont need to use `IN` when using where_in `$this->db->where_in('lookbook_id', $pointid);`

Comment: `$pointid` and `lookbook_id` is different

Comment: Use your variables I just gave an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `where` instead and to construct your `IN` clause there:

```
$this->db->where('lookbook_id IN (SELECT lookbook_id FROM shopify_point WHERE point_id = $pointid)', NULL, FALSE);
```